# "netIn" in mongostat output

Tags: mongodb

I have wrote a test script which did millions of updates(using update query) in a collection. Following is the mongostat output

insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults locked % idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
     0      0  21156      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     81.7          0       0|8     0|9     2m     1k    10   12:52:11
 
     0      0  20620      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     82.5          0       0|8     0|9     1m     1k    10   12:52:12
     0      0  21915      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     81.9          0       0|8     0|9     2m     1k    10   12:52:13
 
     0      0  21634      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     82.1          0       0|8     0|9     2m     1k    10   12:52:15
 
     0      0  19793      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     81.8          0       0|8     0|9     1m     1k    10   12:52:16 
     0      0  22062      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     81.9          0       0|8     0|8     2m     1k    10   12:52:17
 
     0      0  23395      0       0       1       0   208m  2.45g   119m      0     81.9          0       0|8     0|8     2m     1k    10   12:52:19

The **netIn** says the total network in bytes per second, i hope. Is there any way to increase the size of **netIn** to some mb, so that i can increase the update statement per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand the netIn statistic. It isn't some limit but the actual amount of data received by MongoDB per interval sample. In other words, the netIn value will increase if you (can) do more updates.

Increasing update throughput itself may be possible but is very application specific.

Comment: Based on the document size the number of updates vary, but the netIn results the same 1m or 2m. I have tried increasing the updates in a single shot with multiple scripts. But it takes up to 15 seconds. So I thought mongodb limits the netIn size, above the limit will be taken to the next second. I need the possible ways to increase the updates per second.

Comment: It's just rounding to the nearest 1mb above 1mb. If they'd print the value in bytes you'd see variation. It's extremely unlikely your network bound and I can guarantee you there's no hard limit on netIn nor is it configurable. Update throughput can be increased by using safe=false (w <= 0) writes, faster disks, etc.